# Cannot Find the Module Error spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, spfx-webparts

I have scaffold-ed an spfx webppart project. But I am getting the following errors on compilation:

->  **Cannot find module 'ToDoWebPartStrings'**

-> **Cannot find module './ToDo.module.scss'**

-> Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher

-> I tried creating an spfx webpart using Angular js. I followed this blog [Build SharePoint Framework client-side web parts with AngularJS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-client-side-web-parts-with-angular-1-x)

Below is a screenshot from the blog:

[image]

Even in the blog, an error is visible which the author has discarded unfortunately. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone who got stuck here,do not get frustrated. Just use this keyword "gulp serve" in the command prompt. Once the workbench is run, the errors go away automatically. This worked at least in my case.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the VS code editor not finding the reference, but it will be resolved at compile time (gulp bundle / gulp serve). If not, double check the value of the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code you can install "SPFx Essentials". Fixed the errors for me.